# Mapping objects from JSON without path in Restkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

I didn't know a better title for that..
I want to map a JSON but the json has this estructure

```
{
   "error_code": "1001",
   "error_message": "There is another session"
}
```

For example, so I have the class error, with that 2 attributes and this is the code of the mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Error class]];
[errorMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"error_code", @"error_code", @"error_message", @"error_message", nil];
[[objectManager mappingProvider] setMapping:errorMapping forKeyPath:@""];
```

And I get this error:

```
Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ""
```

Thank you